# DataTables with Hidden rows - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Tags: php, html, datatables

I'm trying to achieve a table with expandable rows.
This is the code i have so far.

```
<table id="something" class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($info as $var) {
        ?>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion<?php echo $var['id'] ?>" class="clickable">
            <td><h4><?php echo $name ?> </h4></td>
            <td class="<?php echo $colors[array_rand($colors)] ?>">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="accordion<?php echo $var['id'] ?>" class = "collapse">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

The table loads without any problem.

My goal is to sort either by Status or Name, and use a few more options of DataTables.

As soon as I load DataTables I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Any idea what can be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a guess: try without the colspan (and make 2 tds instead). I bet DT is trying to set an unique id to that "missing" second cell.

Comment: That kind of works...but at the same time generates a bunch load of empty rows and I lose the accordion capability

Answer (score 1):

I had this same thing and none of the ideas above fixed it for me. This one was a bit of head scratcher until I got it figured out.

My table has only two columns and I'm using a `<tr><td colspan="2"><td></tr>` from time to time. The table is syntactically correct. I'm using the colspans to separate logical sections of data.

The error comes from the fact that I'm using HTML5 data attributes on the `<td>` tags. Specifically the data-order attribute. In this case Datatabes does not support colspans on `<td>` tags.

To get this to work properly for me I replaced the `<td colspan="2">` tag with two `<td>` tags that included the data-order attributes. I used the same attribute value for the row coming next so that the order doesn't get wonky when the order is changed.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Well done! They have the same issue on their own forum, check it [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/89802/#Comment_89802) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why yet, but it seems to be related to the "table-stiped" class. Solution, right after your javascript code to "convert" your table to a DataTable you can add the class "table-striped" and that will work, like this:

```
$('#something').addClass("table-striped");
```